# In SQL Server, how to filter lots of elements across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I have a table, `t1`, with columns such as `name`, `code1`, `code2`,..., `code20`

There are, say, 100K rows.

I have another look up table, `t2`, which has one column, `code`; it has 10k rows and each row has a code. So, totally there are 10K codes in this 1-column table.

I need to filter out all the rows in `t1` that have the codes in `t2` from any column, i.e. columns `code1` to `code20`. In other words, in each row in `t1`, once a column has one of the codes in `t2`, it should be captured.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's a pretty funky DB design.  Is changing the schema around a bit an option for you?

Comment: There *would be* an easy way if you had a proper database design - e.g. if you had linked `t1` to a list of codes via a 1:n relationship (instead of having `Code1`...`Code20` in your `t1` table). Why this screwed up design, there is no easy way .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `not exists`:

```
select t1.*
from t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from t2
                  where t2.code = t1.code1 or
                        t2.code = t1.code2 or
                        . . .
                        t2.code = t1.code20
                 );
```

It is tempting to use `in` as the condition in the nested select, but this behaves in a funky way with `NULL`s.  The sequence of direct comparisons is easier.

That said, having 20 columns with the same type of data is usually a sign of poor table design.  More typically, the data would be in some sort of association/junction table, with the 20 columns each appearing in their own row.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to pivot the data in Table t1 then join on t2. 
So instead of t1 where you have name, code1, code2,...Code 20 you would pivot t1 to 
just Name and Code columns then join on t2. 
Alternatively you could just perform separate joins of t1 on t2 for each of t2's columns Code 1 to 20 and union the result.
That's if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Gordon's answer is better than my join solution, but I thought he was looking for matches. Small point: should the code above not have "exists" instead of "not exists"? I thought he wants to "capture" the matches